# How to create valid CSV file with DictWriter in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I create CSV file with this code below:

```
dwf = open(file_name, 'w')
fw = csv.DictWriter(dwf, fieldnames=fields, delimiter='\t')
fw.writeheader()

data_dict = {'name':name, 'text': text, 'type':type 'URL': this_url}
fw.writerow(data_dict)
```

The 'text' field contains textual data, and when I created the 'text' variable, I did this:

```
text = text.strip().replace('\t', '  ').replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', ' ')
```

I intended to remove any potential trouble maker that may be a column delimiter. But still, the csv file created is sometimes invalid, because when I opened it in Numbers on my Mac, some columns are in the same column, not alined with the delimiter.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `quoting` parameter of `csv.DictWriter` to make sure that all of the fields are wrapped with quotes.

```py
csv.DictWriter(dwf, fieldnames=fields, delimiter="\t", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_ALL

Comment: Any downside of using the quoting parameter? I rarely see this in examples.

Comment: It can make the file size a bit bigger, since it has to fit all of the quotation marks, but it's not a big deal. If size is that much of an issue, you could use `csv.QUOTE_NON_NUMERIC` instead, but if file size is already a concern you should be compressing it as a gzip or zip archive anyway.